# Nib files cannot be loaded by name from main bundle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, nsbundle, octest

It seems as though my nib files are included in my test target, they don't exist in the main bundle, so my app crashes on me when I am loding a nib by its name from the main bundle. I either need to find the correct bundle that includes my nib file, or I need to load a nib using a path.

Does anyone have a solution for either one? `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]` doesn't work. I think the nib and class files are not in the same bundle

Comment: What is your code for loading the nib?

Comment: who is self object here?

Comment: @samfisher a subclass of UIView

Comment: Did you check your build phases to see if the NIBs are being copied to your apps' bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to enumerate the bundles

```
for (NSBundle *bundle in [NSBundle allBundles])
{
    // can look for resources in bundle
    locatedPath = [bundle pathForResource:resourcePath ofType:type];

    // or maybe trying and load the nib from it?
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithName:@"Blah" bundle:bundle];

    // check for !nil ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so I found out that the crash was on UIFont, because the font I have in my nib does not exist on OSX. So this helped me go farther on my unit testing.

Comment: Cool - this is the approach I use to load resource files from my unit tests.  In my case, I was loading fake response from a fake web server.  Glad it helped.